# Difference between "get in touch with" and "contact"

Tags: difference

What's difference between the following sentences:

> Thanks for *getting in touch with* us.

AND

> Thanks for *contacting* us.

Comment: "Contacting with us" is ungrammatical.

Comment: @RuchirM is it grammatical: "thanks for contacting us" ?

Comment: Yes. It is grammatical.

Comment: They are essentially the same. "in touch with" connotes more of a reciprocal action, perhaps. "contact" might sound more like a letter was delivered or a message was left and "get in touch with" might sound more like a conversation took place, but either phrase could just about as easily describe either set of events.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existing comments have clarified that it should be 'getting in touch with' or 'contacting'.
'Contacting with' doesn't work, though 'getting in contact with' is possible - I just wouldn't use it in either of the above structures.

I would also change the 'thanks'..

'getting in touch' is informal, so the structure

> "Thanks for getting in touch with us"

works perfectly well.

On the other hand 'contacting us' is much more formal & I would prefer to see it book-ended with 'Thank you'

> "Thank you for contacting us"

Answer (score 1):

In practice, there is little, if any, difference between the two. Both are acceptable for business use. However, *getting in touch with* can mean establishing a relationship, while *contacting* is strictly about the communication transaction.  For example, it is possible for someone to *get in touch with his feelings* or *get in touch with his feminine side*.  On the other hand, *contacting his feelings* is altogether wrong, and *contacting his feminine side* would imply a multiple-personality disorder.